# Allow selection of country & zoom in only to country level

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, maps

I want to use google map but only at the country level i.e i want to show whole  world map in single window and user should be able to  select any country on clicking of the country , also i should be able to show some popups .I also want to get the value of country selected from JS. Please guide me on this. I did google on this but no complete info.

Comment: [Zoom to country](http://geocodezip.com/v3_zoom2countrySelectList.html) - [clickable world map](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_world_countries_simple.html)

Comment: Thanks for input the problem with Zooom to country example is We need to select the country from the drop down cant user place the mouse and select and higlight

Comment: Can't really "select and highlight".  You can combine the 2 examples, click on a country and zoom to its bounds as returned by the geocoder.

Comment: is there an option for multiple select , can we do only highlight

Answer (score 0):

Combine these two examples:

1. [Zoom to country](http://geocodezip.com/v3_zoom2countrySelectList.html)
2. [clickable world map](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_world_countries_simple.html)

[click to zoom to country](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_click2zoom2country.html)

```
var map=null;
var geocoder = null;
var kmlLayer = null;
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); // InfoWindow

function openIW(layerEvt) {
  if (layerEvt.row) {
    var content = layerEvt.row['admin'].value;
  } else if (layerEvt.featureData) {
    var content = layerEvt.featureData.name;
  }
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "you clicked on:<br>"+content;
  findAddress(content);
}

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(36.4278,-15.9);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: chicago,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function() {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "";
  });


  kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/world_countries_kml.xml', {preserveViewport: true, suppressInfoWindows: true} );
  kmlLayer.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', openIW);

}    

function findAddress(address) {
  if ((address != '') && geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         if (results && results[0] && results[0].geometry && results[0].geometry.viewport) 
           map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
         } else {
           alert("No results found");
         }
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: is there by any chance an option for multiple select

Comment: Of course there is.  You just have to define the functionality and code it.

Comment: The only way to create an image out of a google map legally is to use [static maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) (read the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) or consult your lawyer to be sure, IANAL)

Comment: if i am paid customer then can i

Comment: IANAL (I am not a Lawyer) and I don't know, that is your responsibility (or your lawyer's) to determine.

Comment: ;) one last question is it possible to click on coutnry and instead of zooming can i somehow highlight it

Comment: Of course you can.  You just need to have the polygon available to do that.

Comment: is there an option where i can cover the country i clicked.

Comment: You have to code that. [Brazil](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_CountryBrowser.html?country=Brazil) - [multiple countries](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_MultiCountryBrowser.html?countries=Afghanistan,Albania,Algeria,United%20States%20of%20America,Brazil)

Comment: from the example that you gave (Brazil) now i want get a static map of this from Google Static Api what should be done.